# Rewriting the mutual information of a linear model through conditional expectation

Tags: linear-model, conditional-expectation, information-theory, mutual-information

I am reading the following paper:

http://web.mit.edu/18.325/www/telatar_capacity.pdf

In this paper we have the following linear model, with $\mathbf{n}$ being additive noise:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y = Hx + n} \quad \mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{C}^{r\times t}, \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^t,\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{C}^r
\end{equation}

The aim on page 10 (section 4.1) is to calculate the mutual information $\mathcal{I}(x;(y,H))=\mathcal{I}(\text{input;output})$. Now the paper performs the following steps:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{(y,H)}) &= \mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{H}) +\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H})\\
&=\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H})\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H}=H)]
\end{align}

---

Now I have difficulties understanding the transiation that is $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H})
= \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H}=H)]$.

1. Could somebody explain/clarify this point? I thought conditioning on RVs $\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H}$ implied I was doing the following: $\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H}=H$, but in the above statement these are separate ideas.
2. Also another question is: what probability distribution is the expectation being taken over?
3. Lastly, would the same equations be obtainable if we consider $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y})$ as this is more direct for the input-output relationship rather than with the $\mathbf{H}$ floating around there in addition. i.e. consider: $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y})$ instead of $\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{H}))$?

Answer (score 2):

Although I find the notation used in the equation quite awkward, I will show you how to establish that result using the same notation.  The [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Conditional_mutual_information) is the expected value of the logarithm of the ratio of the joint density divided by the product of the marginal densities.  Thus, for the variables in question, you have:

$$\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{(y,H)})
=\mathbb{E} \Bigg( \log \bigg(\frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})} \bigg) \Bigg).$$

Now, note that:

$$\frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})}
= \frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})}
\cdot \frac{p(\mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{H})}
= \frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}| \mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}| \mathbf{H})}.$$

Thus, using the [law of iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) we can write the mutual information as:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{(y,H)})
&= \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \log \bigg(\frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H})} \bigg) \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \log \bigg(\frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}| \mathbf{H})}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}| \mathbf{H})} \bigg) \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}_H \Bigg( \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \log \bigg(\frac{p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}| \mathbf{H}=H)}{p(\mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{y}| \mathbf{H}=H)} \bigg) \Bigg) \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}_H \Big( \mathcal{I}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{H} = H) \Big). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

As you can see, nothing in this working requires you to be using a linear model.  It is a general result that applies regardless of the relationship of the random variables under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

1.

To understand the answer to your first question, we first need to understand what **mutual information** is and how it is different from **conditional mutual information**.

For random variables $X$ and $Y$ with distributions $P_{X}$ and $P_{Y}$ respectively, mutual information $I(X; Y)$ is **a measure of independence** between $P_{X}$ and $P_{Y}$, defined as the KL-divergence between the joint distribution $P_{(X, Y)}$ and the product of marginals $P_{X} \otimes P_{Y}$ as follows:
$$
  I(X; Y) = D_{KL}(P_{(X, Y)} || P_{X} \otimes P_{Y}).
$$
If $P_{(X, Y)} = P_{X} \otimes P_{Y}$ then then $X$ and $Y$ are independent and hence $I(X; Y) = 0$ and the same goes from the other direction. In other words, $I(X; Y)$ measures the amount of information about $X$ we get after observing $Y$ and vice-versa.

Now let $Z$ be some other random variable with distribution $P_{Z}$. Suppose we have observed $Z = z$. Conditionally on this **new information**, the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ may have changed. For example, if $Z = (X, Y)$, then observing $X$ does not provide any new information about $Y$, since all of it is already contained in the random variable $Z$.
To account for this new information, we can compute a refined measure of independence between the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. In particular, we can let $P_{X \mid Z=z}$ and $P_{Y \mid Z = z}$ denote the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ conditionally on $Z = z$ and let
$$
 I(X;Y \mid Z = z) = D_{KL}(P_{(X, Y) \mid Z = z} || P_{X \mid Z=z} \otimes P_{Y \mid Z=z}).
$$

With the above notation at hand, we can now say what the difference between
$I(X;Y \mid Z)$ and $I(X;Y \mid Z = z)$ is.
The former is formally a **random-variable**, while the latter is a **number**. The **conditional mutual information** is **defined** to be the expected value of $I(X;Y \mid Z)$ -- that is, what is the **average** measure of independence between $X$ and $Y$ after observing $Z$, which is typically denoted by the following rather unfortunate, overloaded notation:
$$
  I(X;Y\mid Z) = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim P_{Z}} I(X;Y \mid Z = z).
$$

2.

Using the above notation $Z = \mathbf{H}$, hence the expectation is taken with respect to $\mathbf{H} \sim P_{\mathbf{H}}$. That is, the design matrix $\mathbf{H}$ is assumed to be random and follows distribution $P_{\mathbf{H}}$.

3.

$I(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y})$ and $I(\mathbf{x}; (\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H}))$ have very different meanings! To appreciate the difference, consider a setting where $r = t$ and suppose that $\mathbf{H}$ is always invertible (that is, $P_{\mathbf{H}}$ is supported on a set of invertible square $t \times t$ matrices). Further, let the additive noise term $\mathbf{n}$ be always $0$. Then
\begin{align}
  \tag{*}
  \mathbf{y} &= \mathbf{Hx},\\
  \mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{H^{-1}y}.
\end{align}
Hence, using the formulas you wrote down we have
$$
  I(\mathbf{x}, (\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H}))
= I(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{H})
$$
which means that $I(\mathbf{x}, (\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{H}))$ is **large**, because knowing $\mathbf{H}$ and one of $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ the other one can be computed exactly using Equation (*) above.

On the other hand,
$$I(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y})$$
is going to be **small**, because without the knowledge of $\mathbf{H}$, $\mathbf{x}$ says nothing about $\mathbf{y}$ and vice-versa.